# Magento How to change the base currency without effecting the cart total calulations

Tags: magento, cart

I changed the base currency of my store from Singapore dollar to Pound sterling. Had to manually change all the product prices as magento doesn't do that automatically. I dont know but after changing the base currency the cart total is correct but the displayed calculation is incorrect.
I have added the cart image for reference, the calculated total is correct but the breakdown is incorrect and doesn't make any sense. Can anyone help please????
[image: Sample Cart Image]

Comment: what is the issue here ? it all seems correct

Comment: If you see the calculation breakdown on the left side, it is all incorrect. The cost of fabric should be £45 x 2m should be £90, whereas it is coming as £51.30 which is incorrect. Also the sewing&Lining cost is coming up very high.